# pagination kaminari no css applyed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I have try `rails g kaminari:views bootstrap3` cmd, it generated views, but no CSS. So the result shown in browser isn't good.

How generate and include kaminari's CSS style ?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap usually works really well with Rails, but in the case of pagination, the stylings are a little off by default. You can quickly getting them back up-to-snuff with something like this **pagination_overrides.scss**:

```
.pagination a, .pagination span.current, .pagination span.gap {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 14px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

.pagination {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
.first{
    padding : 0;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
.prev {
    padding : 0;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
.page{
    padding : 0;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
.next{
    padding : 0;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
.last{
    padding : 0;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Hm, try do this: `<%= paginate @posts, theme: 'bootstrap3', pagination_class: "pagination-centered" %>`

Comment: error : ```Missing partial kaminari/bootstrap3/_paginator``` my installation log: http://pastebin.com/KWWb7tc4

Comment: Is there a possibility to take a look on yours app sources?

Comment: about what part of the app? (it not online for now)

Comment: It's interesting to look at app/assets and app/views.

Comment: In fact, CSS is just not supported: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/issues/34 we have to include it ourself. I copy the css on bootstrap, it's good now ;)

Comment: What exactly you added? It's really interesting why **pagination_overrides.scss** styling doesn't work for you?

Comment: I include CSS present on this page : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination (only relative to pagination)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the pagination css would not display under my namespaced admin area, adding https://github.com/matenia/bootstrap-kaminari-views fixed it for me.